# Post part of a form Asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, textbox, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a form including two textboxes, two dropdownlists and one label. When I fill the first two textboxes and select values of the two dropdownlists, all the values will be concatenated and put into the label one. So now when I click button Save, I want to post only the value of the label, not these other textboxes and checklists. How can I provoke the post method for the label and disable the method for these other ones?
Below is my code so far:

```
   <div class="panel-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            @Html.Label("Part/Location", new {@class = "control-label"})
                            @Html.TextBox("PartLocation", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            @Html.Label("Index", new {@class = "control-label"})
                            @Html.TextBox("Index", null , new {@class = "form-control"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            @Html.Label("Measurement", new {@class = "control-label"})
                            @Html.DropDownList("Measurements", "Select measurement")
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChannelGroupId)

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            @Html.Label("Location", new {@class = "control-label"})
                            @Html.DropDownList("DirectionTypes","Select direction")
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChannelGroupId)

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChannelGroupId, new {@class = "control-label"})
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ChannelGroupId, Model.ChannelGroups, "Select Channel Group", new {@class = "form-control"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChannelGroupId)

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label"></label>
                            <a href="#" id="addChannelGroup" class="form-control" style="border: none">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle">Add Group</i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.Label("Channel name: ", new { id = "channelName",@class = "control-label" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

And this is Jquery handling concatenation:

```
 $("#PartLocation, #Index,#Measurements,#DirectionTypes").change(function () {
        var partLocationText = $("#PartLocation").val();
        var indexText = $("#Index").val();
        var mesurementSelected = $("#Measurements option:selected").text();
        var directionSelected = $("#DirectionTypes option:selected").text();

            $("#channelName").empty();
            $("#channelName").append("Channel name: " + partLocationText + "_" + indexText);

        if (mesurementSelected != "Select measurement") {
            $("#channelName").append("_" + mesurementSelected);
        }
        if (directionSelected != "Select direction") {
            $("#channelName").append("_" + directionSelected);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things you can do here to achieve what you want.
1. According to HTML specs all the HTML controls (inputs, selects) wont post if they dont have a name attribute. So Simple removing the name attributes from these controls will stop them from posting their values. In addition to this because a labels values isnt posted back you will also have to create a hidden textbox update its value to the concatenated values(ie value of the label) and then allow the post to happen.

```
$(function(){
 $("#PartLocation, #Index,#Measurements,#DirectionTypes").removeAttr('name');
 //this will remove their name attribute and hence their values wont be posted back
})
```

and to update the value of a hidden textbox (input[type="text"]).

```
$("#PartLocation, #Index,#Measurements,#DirectionTypes").change(function () {
       //your code
       //let cs be the final concatenated string.
       $("#channelName").append(cs);
       $('#hiddenInput').val(cs);
    });
```

2. You can just take over the posting mechanism by Javascript and post only the value you want to post. Obviously for this to happen you should ideally change the return type of your Action Method to `HttpResult` OR `JsonResult` whichever is more appropriate for you.

```
$(function(){
$('form').submit(function(f, e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //callculate your concatenated string.
  //assumed to be cs
  $.ajax(url/*url to ur post action method*/, {
   //fill in the suitable params see the jquery link for more help
  })
})
})
```

[JQUERY AJAX LINK](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)